# Query not returning results, left join

Tags: mysql

I have two tables and I am attempting to query and use a left join to grab the results. The issues is that my query is not returning any records.

My first table has all of my artists:

**Artist**

```
id | name
------------------------
4    Damien Rice
5    John Mayer 
6    Pink Floyd
```

My second table has all of the artist genres

**ArtistGenre**

```
id | artist_id | genre_name
------------------------
7     6         Jam
17    6         Rock
16    6         Blues
```

My query, but it returns no results.

```
SELECT    a.*, ag.*
FROM      Artist a
LEFT JOIN ArtistGenre ag
ON        ag.artist_id=a.id
WHERE     a.id IS NOT NULL
AND       ag.id IN (7,17,16)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Your `where` condition is converting the `left join` to an `inner join` (because non-matching rows have a value of `NULL` for `ag.id` which fails the `IN`).  Move the second condition to the `on` clause:

```
SELECT a.*, ag.*
FROM Artist a LEFT JOIN
     ArtistGenre ag
     ON ag.artist_id = a.id AND ag.id IN (7, 17, 16)
WHERE a.id IS NOT NULL;
```

Comment: This ends up returning all of the artists and not just artist "Pink Floyd" (id 6).

Comment: @LargeTuna . . . Your question doesn't specify what you are trying to do.  It really just shows a query that has a left join being turned into an inner join.  That would seem to be the obvious problem in such a case.

Comment: Sorry, I just want to return any artist that has matching genres "IN"7, 17, 16. In this case it would only be artist id 6 who is pink floyd